# How to fix Warning: strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I can't remove strlen from this function to count. How can I use array and strlen in one function like this?

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['cek'])) {
function match( $text, $pattern ) {
    $count=0;
    $split_words = explode(' ', $text );
     $cek = 0;
     $n=strlen($split_words);
     $m=strlen($pattern);

 for ($i = 0; $i <= $n - $m; $i++) {
    $j = 0;
    while ($j < $m && $split_words[$i + $j] == $pattern[$j]){
       echo $j++;
    }
    if ($j >= $m) {
     echo  $cek++;

       }

 }
 if ($cek > 0) {
    echo "matched";
     $count;
 } else {
   echo  "didn't match ";
 }
}
$banned_words = array('badword1','badword2','badword3','badword4','badword5','badword6','badword7');
$teks = $_POST['teks'];
echo   match($teks, $banned_words);
$count2 = match($teks,$banned_words);
if ($count2 != 0) {
echo $count2;
echo 'blocked!';
}else{
echo $count2;
echo 'Text valid';
}
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <form method="post">
<input type="text" name="teks"/>
<button type="submit" name="cek">Submit</button>
```

**OUTPUT**

> Warning: strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\kmp\bs.php on line 7
>   Warning: strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\kmp\bs.php on line 8
>   0matched
>   Warning: strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\kmp\bs.php on line 8
>   0matchedText valid

Comment: `$m=strlen($pattern);` this line, then you pass `$pattern` as an array - which you can't count the length of the string - because it's not a string, its an array. If you can explain a bit more specific what you want the function to do, there is likely an easier approach to it.

Comment: Are you trying to count the number of elements in `$split_words`?

Comment: If you are looking to count the number of items in the array, you can use `count()` instead of `strlen()`

Comment: @Qirel I wanna use brute force algorithm to match data. For example I will input data like this '**badword1 make me badword2**'. I want to compare the data from input data with array data(banned_words). So I will convert input data to array data then compare them in order to count  'the badwords'.

Comment: How about a regex approach? https://eval.in/586251 You probably also should add word boundaries. If that works let me know and I'll post as answer.

Comment: @chris85 I really appreciate if you wanna help me, but I have to use brute force algorithm because in my proposal I wrote brute force to fix this problem. I have  browsed on the internet, ask someone who I expected can help me, read  algorithm books, but it still can't solve this problem. Is it imposible to use brute force to solve this case?

Answer (score 0):

> Q: How to fix Warning: strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given?

**Short answer:  To fix this error, you just need to pass string as an argument instead of array. Like it says.**

It seems, that one of your strlens' parameters is not a string (either `$split_words` or `$pattern`)

Moreover `$split_words` seems to be an array because it's the result of [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php). If you want to count number of elements in array use [count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) instead of [strlen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php)

Example of strlen()

```
$string = 'test';
echo strlen($string);
```

prints: 4

Comment: can you give the example?

Comment: This isn't really relevant for what the OP is trying to do. A link to the manual as comment would have given OP more information, http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help.
You can count the string length like this:

```
<?php

$text = 'Hello this is a string';

$split_words = explode(' ', $text );

$count = 0;

foreach($split_words as $value){
    $count+= strlen($value);
};

echo $count;
```